# Django with database on SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have a project working with sqlite3 (default database) and I am trying to use Microsoft SQL Server instead.

I was following [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/python-sql-driver-pymssql?view=sql-server-2017) and I have already installed the `pymssql` package, but right now I don't know what I need to do to connect my Django to my SQL Server database.

Comment: you need to add DATABASE settings( credentials) to your `settings.py`

Comment: In addition to @ans2human, you could also follow this doc: https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation

Comment: You can use MSSQL database backend. find more documentation from [here](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [django-mssql](https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package:

1. Install the package via PIP :  `pip install django-mssql`
2. Add relevant settings of your DB to `settings.py`.

   ```
   DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'NAME': 'my_database',
       'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',   # <-- don't change this as this is module name 
       'HOST': 'dbserver\\ss2012',
       'USER': '',
       'PASSWORD': '',
    }
   }
   ```

> **Do not include a django.db.backends. prefix. That is only for core backends that are included with Django, not 3rd party backends.**

Comment: already try that and is always giving me this error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlserver_ado' isn't an available database backend.`

Answer (score 1):

In order the ORM to work as expected you have to use a database backend. You can't just set the driver to pymssql because the ORM doesn't know how to use it. 
Keep in mind that at this point there is no official myssql database backend released by Django. django-mssql might do the job but the last supported Django version is 1.8.

I suggest you to try https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/. It looks like it supports Django 2.1. But you will have to use pyodbc instead of pymssql.

Comment: already try that , and is allways giving me this error `
The data source name was not found and no default driver(SQLDriverConnect) was specified)`

Comment: well i already found the solution and put  `DRIVER={SQL Server}` but now i have another error that i cant import the models to the sql